# What are the possibilities of the general fibres in an Iitaka fibration?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry, characteristic-p, kodaira-dimension

This question is motivated by complex algebraic geometry.

If $X$ is a complex algebraic variety with Kodaira dimension in $[1,\dim X-1]$, then the [Iitaka fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iitaka_dimension) (the rational map induced by the linear system $|mK_X|$ for $m$ divisible and large enough) has its general fibre of Kodaira dimension $0$.

This is not the case in char. $p$. In char. $2$ and $3$, there are quasi-elliptic fibrations where the general fibres are rational curves with a single cusp.

**Question:** Are these (elliptic curve & rational curve with cusp) the only possibilities of general fibres in a codimension-1 Iitaka fibration?

More generally, what are the possibilities of the general fibres in an Iitaka fibration?

Comment: I think those are the only two possibilities.